# How do I interact with arrays in inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I have an array defined in C++, and I am using _asm to write my program in assembly. How would I move a specific element of the array into a register. For example, if I had an variable named i1, I know it would be this:

```
int i1 = 3;

_asm
{
    mov eax, i1
}
```

But how would I do that with an array? Below is the code that I tried, and it didn't work, and after doing some research I couldn't really find anything helpful on it.

```
int array[2] = {10, 20};

_asm
{
    mov eax, array[0]
}
```

Side note: I don't think this is important but I'm working in Visual Studio

Comment: Define _"it didn't work"_. What happened exactly?

Comment: usually in (non-inline) assembly, you'd do `mov eax, [array+n*4]`, where `n` is the offset (e.g., `array[n]`), and `4` is the sizeof element type, (usually `int`s are of size 4). MSVC inline assembly may have specific syntax for that though.

Comment: @C.Dunn `array` probably expands to something like `[ebp-4]`, but normally the assembler should be able to handle expressions like `[ebp-4][0]`.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm used to NASM assembly, which has rather forgiving syntax for effective addresses. `array` in this case could be a label or `equ` referring to the stack like you said.